# How to install zotero in ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, zotero

I download the tar.bz file from the home page of zotero, extract it and run the file 'run-zotero.sh', but it open zotero rather than install it. How to install it? Any help or suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: which version of Ubuntu you are using ??

Comment: I use ubuntu 13.04

Comment: Just a quick note to let you know there is a github repo that should help all debian-based distro to install it with minimal hassle:
https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-deb
Best

Comment: Just install via snap, as mentioned by @Mark answer.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

As of 2019, the preferred way of installing Zotero is by using [Emiliano Heyns' packages](https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-deb).

Run the following instructions on your terminal:

```sh
wget -qO- https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-deb/releases/download/apt-get/install.sh | sudo bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install zotero
```

For additional information about the provided packages, see the [README file](https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-deb/blob/master/README.md).

Other answers should be considered obsolete, Sebastiaan Mathot's packages being [no longer maintained](https://launchpad.net/~smathot/+archive/ubuntu/cogscinl).

Comment: I ran into an problem with this -- it looks like the repo has a hosting problem and so the owner recommends installing from Sourceforge for now. For more info see the readme and issue https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-deb/issues/49

Comment: *the preferred way* is now probably snap, as it is available out of the box in the Ubuntu snap repos

Comment: The updated source is:

curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/retorquere/zotero-deb/master/install.sh | sudo bash

Answer (score 49):

I suggest you add a ppa so that the program gets updated regularly:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:smathot/cogscinl
```

Say yes/press enter to accept any requests.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

wait for it to complete, then:

```
sudo apt-get install zotero-standalone
```

This will install the program.

Comment: I try this code, but 'E: Unable to locate package zotero-standalone
'.

Comment: Actually this PPA is only for upto 12.10 but OP using 13.04 .sp it doesnt work for him.

Comment: Well I was able to install it from 13.04 using the commands I gave. Eden, did you run the second command after running the first?

Comment: Yeah, I run all the command in order.

Comment: @rajagenupula Maybe you are right. I try other software only upto 12.10 with the same question.

Comment: Working with 14.04 for me :)

Comment: ... also on 14.10 and 15.04.

Comment: tried on 16.04 and works

Comment: This works on later versions of ubuntu, but it can later on fail to update to later versions of Zotero, which severely diminishes its usefulness.

Comment: works on ubuntu 17.10

Comment: works on ubuntu 18 LTS

Comment: The following packages are *no longer maintained*:

- Zotero standalone, a reference manager
  <http://www.zotero.org/>
  For an alternative installer, see <https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-deb>

Answer (score 15):

[This](https://github.com/smathot/zotero_installer) project is designed to automate installation. It worked for me with 13.04. To install it, run the following in your terminal:

```
wget https://raw.github.com/smathot/zotero_installer/master/zotero_installer.sh -O /tmp/zotero_installer.sh
chmod +x /tmp/zotero_installer.sh
/tmp/zotero_installer.sh
```

and answer the questions. If you want it to be installed globally, you will need sudo on the last command:

```
sudo /tmp/zotero_installer.sh
```

Answer (score 7):

I have installed Zotero on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS recently.

This is how I have done:

- First I downloaded the tarball from the [Zotero Download page](https://www.zotero.org/download/), extract its contents to a folder named `Zotero_linux-x86_64`.
- Then I ran the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo mv -v Zotero_linux-x86_64 /opt/zotero/
ln -s /opt/zotero/zotero.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/zotero.desktop
sudo /opt/zotero/set_launcher_icon
```

That's it. The installation's completed.

Comment: Last command should be 'sudo /opt/zotero/set_launcher_icon', or cd to /opt/zotero/ before it.

Comment: I have updated it, thanks.

Comment: Very straightforward, and the only answer where setting `zotero.desktop` worked, +1 thanks!

Comment: @jay.sf I'm glad to know that my answer has helped you.

Comment: The answer I avoided out of lazyness but the only one that delivered me the newest zotero version I needed.

Comment: Just install via snap, just one line, and DONE. Follow @Mark answer

Answer (score 7):

It's 2022 and Zotero is available as a [snap](https://ubuntu.com/blog/whats-in-a-snap) in Ubuntu. A version of Zotero can be installed without having to add additional repositories (although you may get a more recent version if you do use some of the techniques from other answers).

To install:

```
snap install zotero-snap
```

Comment: easy-peasy! thanks. Please make this the default answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have searched and came to know that , there only standalone Zotero PPA not yet made for Ubuntu 13.04 . you can run it as you've done with the script upto PPA made.

but Ubuntu have a good Documentation for Zotero that can help you to get more information on usage of it.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Zotero

Comment: Thanks! I make it a startup application and this will be ok.

Answer (score 1):

I found a help here
https://www.linuxhelp.com/how-to-install-zotero-in-ubuntu/

The steps in the terminal are

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:smathot/cogscinl`

Type your password and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> when asked.

2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install zotero-standalone`

This will install Zotero

Comment: Same thing as described in https://askubuntu.com/a/332117/15003.

Comment: How is this answer different from @Boluc Papuccuoglu's? `add-apt-repository` is a symlink, this should have been a comment below the aforementioned answer at most.

Comment: Also they are no longer maintaining it.

Answer (score 0):

The [zotero installation page](https://www.zotero.org/support/installation) has decent instructions but they should have supplied the commands.  Below are the commands I used (assuming the downloads folder is where your downloaded tar ball ended up):

```
cd /opt/
sudo mkdir zotero
cd ~/Downloads/
sudo tar -xf Zotero-6.0.9_linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 -C /opt/zotero/
cd /opt/zotero/Zotero_linux-x86_64/
sudo ./set_launcher_icon
ln -s /opt/zotero/Zotero_linux-x86_64/zotero.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/zotero.desktop
```

A quick script could be made from these simple commands if desired.